# Reuse Gradle build script in other projects

Tags: gradle, groovy

Let's say I have:

- project A containing a build.gradle script which applies another script build-A.gradle containing a bunch of tasks
- project B where I want to use tasks from build-A.gradle

build-A.gradle looks like this:

```
task someTask << {
   // do stuff
}
```

It seems that solution is to create a standalone custom Gradle plugin, so I've created project C for that. It contains copypasted build-A.gradle script and MyPlugin class extending Plugin with `apply(Project project)` method.

1. Is there any way to refer to tasks declared in my build-A.gradle from MyPlugin?
2. If not, how can I "convert" my script into task classes? E.g. how can get hold of the properties like `configurations`, `ant`, etc. from the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to refer to tasks declared in my build-A.gradle from
>   MyPlugin?

Since you've created ProjectC you could put `build-A.gradle` in `ProjectC/src/main/resources/build-A.gradle` so that it's packed inside the plugin jar and available on the classpath. Then you could do the following in `ProjectC/src/main/groovy/.../MyPlugin.groovy`

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        applyFromClasspath(project, 'build-A.gradle')
    }

    void applyFromClasspath(Project project, String path) {
        InputStream in = getClass().classloader.getResourceAsStream(path)
        if (in == null) throw new RuntimeException("No such resource $path")
        in.withStream { InputStream stream ->
            File localFile = project.file("${project.buildDir}/MyPlugin/$path")
            localFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
            localFile.bytes = stream.bytes
        }
        project.apply(from: localFile)
    }
}
```

> how can get hold of the properties like configurations, ant, etc. from
>   the classes?

These are available from the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance (eg `project.configurations` and `project.ant` etc). The `Project` object is implicit in a `build.gradle` file so `configurations` will delegate to `project.configurations` etc. If you'd like the same in a plugin you can use `project.with { ... }`. Eg:

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.with {
        configurations { ... }
        ant.echo(message: 'Hello')
    }
}
```

@see [Object.with(Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)